# Unable to print data into different columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to **scrape** data from URLs and creating following dataframes

```
data_urls_scraped2 = pd.DataFrame(data_urls_scraped)
titles2 = pd.DataFrame(titles)
subtitles2 = pd.DataFrame(subtitles)

df_subtitles = subtitles2
df_subtitles['Sub_titles'] = df_subtitles[df_subtitles.columns[1:]].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x.dropna().astype(str)), axis=1)
df_subtitles2 = df_subtitles['Sub_titles']

res = pd.concat([data_urls_scraped2, titles2, df_subtitles2])
res.columns = ['Urls', 'Title', 'Sub_titles']
res.to_csv('combined1.csv')
```

ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 3 elements

and if i used following code it don't put data in different columns.

```
res = pd.concat([data_urls_scraped2, titles2, df_subtitles2])
res.columns = ['Urls']
res.to_csv('combined1.csv')
```

[image]

Comment: perfect. thanks Andrej

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put `axis=1` to `pd.concat`:

```py
res = pd.concat([data_urls_scraped2, titles2, df_subtitles2], axis=1)
res.columns = ['Urls', 'Title', 'Sub_titles']
res.to_csv('combined1.csv')
```